# Emacs Haskell indentation

Tags: emacs, haskell, indentation

Please help me set up proper indentation in Emacs haskell-mode

When I'm trying to type down something like ADT or a record, I'm getting on the wrong column after pressing `<ENTER>`, and pressing `<TAB>` ***won't*** switch to the right one until I enter either `|` or ';'!

```
data MyADT = Oh
           | Hi
           | Hello
             | <- the cursor is here again!
```

Trying to solve the problem I set

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "RET") 'reindent-then-newline-and-indent)
```

in my `.emacs` file, but it won't indent the current line on pressing `<enter>` too!

Another strange behaviour: indentation of case

```
oneChar c =  case lookup c simpleEscapes of
  | <- what? here?!
```

Comment: The `case` case is correct behavior.

Comment: If you press tab twice, it inserts a '|' in correct indentation.

Comment: if there is no `|` yet, it doesn't. So I have to type something in the line before pressing tab

Comment: @jrockwaym, even the first one can be considered correct by someone

Comment: Probably, what is needed is to implement some different indentation algorithm for different people.  We need some emacs guru, here.

Comment: I agree with jrockway that this the behaviour on oneChar is correct. Inserting next level of indent with 2 spaces is sufficient. Entering | beneath "case" will give you way too much whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I commented the line

```
;;(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indent)
```

And now I'm getting a good "tab" behavior: at least, it allows me to choose a column and does not tie down me to the one it likes. But no auto-indent at all annoys me a little bit, so I'm hoping it is a temporary solution

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you type `<Enter>` and then "`|`" and then `<Tab>`. If I do that, I get the same results. But if I type `<Enter>` and then `<Tab>` and then `<Tab>` again it automatically inserts the "`|`" and lines it up correctly, like so:

```
data MyADT = Oh
           | Hi
           |<Cursor>
```

When I check my haskell-mode version using `M-x eval-expression haskell-version <Enter>` I get "v2_4".

Emacs haskell-mode doesn't fully analyze the source code, so the "automatic" features are approximate, I think. Typing `<Tab>` several times on a new line cycles through several possible indentations, and also sometimes inserts text like the "`|`" for algebraic data types.

Answer (score 4):

*Caveat:* I'm not a Haskell user, so take this with a grain of salt.

When you press <kbd>RET</kbd> after the `Hello`, Emacs doesn't know you're going to add a `|` ([quick search](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Type_declarations) shows you can have other symbols).  The Haskell folks have deemed the proper indentation to be lined up directly below the `H` in `Hello`.  If the indentation were to automatically line up with the `|` on the line above, then all the cases where you *don't* type a `|` will result in improper indentation.  Damned if you do, damned if you don't...

Other programming modes (C/C++, Lisp, Tcl, ...) have the same problem - they cannot know ahead of time what you're going to put on the next line, so the indentation my not be what you'd hoped for.

One solution is to use ["electric"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Electric-C.html) keys, which is to say that they insert characters and also force re-indentation.  You could easily define <kbd>|</kbd> to be electric with the following code:

```
(defun haskell-electric-| ()
  "it's electric!  (insert | and indent as long as the | follows whitespace)"
  (interactive)
  (insert "|")
  (if (string-match-p "^\\s-*|" (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) 
                                                  (point)))
      (haskell-indentation-indent-line)))
(define-key haskell-mode-map "|" 'haskell-electric-|)
```

I added a check to ensure that the `|` inserted is preceded by only whitespace, you can customize that however you want or remove the check altogether.

I presume there might also be other symbols in Haskell that would be worth making electric.